# 8 Queens Python implementation empty lists

Tags: python

```
def check(a,i):
   n = len(a)
   return not (i in a or
               i+n in [a[j]+j for j in range(n)] or
               i-n in [a[j]-j for j in range(n)]) 

def rsearch(N):
   global a
   global b

   if len(a) == N:
      b.append(a) #<-- this works HERE
      print(a) #<-- this also works HERE
      return True

   z = False
   for i in range(N):
      if check(a,i):
         a.append(i)
         z = rsearch(N) or z
         del a[-1]
   return z


a = []
b = []
rsearch(8)
print(a) #<-- empty list ??
print(b) #<-- list of 92 empty lists ?? ??
print(len(b)) #<-- returns 92
```

So I have this implementation for the 8 Queens problem written in Python, it works but I'm having some issues formatting. 
in my `len(a) == N` check I print the solution list, works fine, I append the solution list to another list, b, which works fine in that moment. But the final `print(a)` gives back an empty list, and `print(b)` gives back a list containing 92 empty lists, it found every solution but they're all empty. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong , why they're empty?

Comment: You are re-using lists. When you clear the last element, `del a[-1]` it's working on a single, *global a*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why `a` is empty: You perform `a.append(i)` followed by `del a[-1]`. This effectively appends an element to `a` and then removes it again. The total count will remain zero therefore.

As to why `b` only contains empty lists: You append `a` to `b` (`b.append(a)`) and hence `b` stores references to the list pointed to by `a`. Since `a` is an empty list, `b` contains 92 (similar) references to the same empty list `a`. If at all you should append a copy of `a`, e.g. `b.append([x for x in a])`.

Comment: but when I check if a's length is equal to 8 and then print a it prints a correct list of 8 integers, is my recursion going too deep and clearing everything after that point or something?

Comment: @NicovanBentum The point is that you print inside the recursion where the items are still present since the items are deleted after each recursive call returned. And since `b` stores references to `a` it is affected by these modifications as well.

Comment: that makes sense thanks, fixed it by doing `b.append(a.copy)` instead.